# How to update product.conf file after upgrade application in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration-files, upstart

I have a conf file product which launches the product application at startup.

Application folder structure:

```
home/
    jamnes/
          product/
                run.sh
```

product.conf file:

```
# Product start file
#
# Starts the Product App and respawns when it quits

description     " Product Application"

start on desktop-session-start
stop on runlevel [!2345]

respawn
exec /home/james/product/run.sh
```

if user upgrade the application we are placing new version different structure

```
home/
    jamnes/
           product/
                  run.sh
           new/
              product/
                     run.sh
```

Issue:

How can i point to new version product from product.conf file

exec /home/james/**new**/product/run.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a symlink `current` in `/home/jamnes/product' pointing, well, to a current version of the product. But your question is unrelated to upstart or ubuntu at all.